# Why does the Google Reports API Java login report always returning is_suspicious=null?

Tags: google-admin-sdk, google-reporting-api

There seems to be an issue with the Reports API not returning the correct value or is_suspicious in the Activities.List login report. The flag always returns null when I use the api programmatically or when I download the report from the Google Admin. However, just viewing the results within the Admin shows a red flag on suspicious logins. Is this a known issue?

Comment: Hi ! Could you please share a sample code with no sensitive data to try to reproduce your issue? Thanks ! :D

Comment: Hi Mateo, it is reproducible using the basic sample code for the Reports API, or the API Explorer on the documentation page (https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/reference/activities/list). As long as you have suspicious logins showing up in your Login Audit Report in the Admin Console you will be able to match those entries to the ones returning from the API and see that "is_suspicious=null" when it is appearing as suspicious in the console

Comment: I figured out my issue. I was calling getValue on is_supicious rather than getBoolValue. Although this brings up a point that there is no way to know what type of value is being returned for a parameter without testing each one to see which does not return null. There should be a parameter type field so you know which of the "get" methods to call

Comment: Hi ! Coul you please formalise your comment explaining the solution into an answer so that other community members with similar issues find the answer easily ? Thanks ! :D